# File.WriteAllText does not overwrite if file exists

Tags: c#

I am checking if a file exists and if it does not, "Create and close". Else, "Overwrite", but the overwrite never occurs and only appends.

```
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
    else
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
```

From MSDN: *Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.*

It's designed to overwrite, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

My full code:

```
static void Save<T, Y>(Dictionary<T,Y> dict, List<Y> list, string path)
    {
        foreach (var val in dict.Values)
            list.Add(val);

        string data = JsonHelper.ToJson(list.ToArray(), true);
        Debug.Log("saving version: " + data);

        string filePath = Application.dataPath + path;

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
        else
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
    }
```

Edit:

I have added:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("never called?");
            File.Delete(filePath);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
        }
```

The debug.log gets called, the delete seems to be skipped over(?) and then WriteAllText makes the file larger, appending duplicates.

**SOLVED**

It was the data that was duplicating itself and not the file. Dictionary didn't allow duplicates, but I was saving a List and then loading it by adding the items from the save file. Lists allow duplicates which in turn looked like I was not overwriting the file.

Comment: what is value for `path`? (show some example)...  and `Application.dataPath`, maybe I wrong, but I can't find something like that... `Application.StartupPath` and so on - yes, but `dataPath` (??)

Comment: Sorry I should mention that "Application.dataPath" is a Unity method.

Comment: Obviously `data` contains the old and the new content, so you are overwriting the file, with wrong data.

Comment: Yea that's right. Just trying to figure out how it managed to get both the old and the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.WriteAllText Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

[File.Delete Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Deletes the specified file.

This is black and white. If anything else is happening, you need to debug your application because either an exception is being thrown, your path is not what you think it is, or the data is not what you think it is. The CLR and the windows API wont roll dice

Good luck

**Update**

> Thank you. I've removed the second file function and left the delete,
>   which I've verified works. I've tried changing the file name in the
>   else argument and that works. Only the data inside remains. **I save a
>   dictionary with if else statements to prevent duplicates, but the file
>   is full of duplicates, so on load an exception is thrown that
>   duplicates exists**.

A dictionary prevents duplicates on the keys not values, values can be duplicated all day long

```
foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
   list.Add(key );
```

or if you want distinct values (depending on the datatype)

```
foreach (var val in dict.Values.Distinct())
   list.Add(val );
```

Comment: Thank you. I've removed the second file function and left the delete, which I've verified works. I've tried changing the file name in the else argument and that works. Only the data inside remains. I save a dictionary with if else statements to prevent duplicates, but the file is full of duplicates, so on load an exception is thrown that duplicates exists.

Comment: You sir, are a genius, it was the data I was saving seems to append itself onto the string.